# React axios always send 4 requests

Tags: reactjs, axios

Look at this below code

```
const Test = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`test-messages`).then((result) => {
      console.log("test");
    });
  });

  return <h1>Test</h1>;
};

export default Test;
```

Problem is that all the times react send 4 request. 2 request (2 returns data from the server). Do you know where problem is?

Answer (score 1):

try to add add [] as dependency

```
const Test = () => {
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`test-messages`).then((result) => {
      console.log("test");
    });
  }, []);

  return <h1>Test</h1>;
};

export default Test;
```

axios.get will be triggered once when component will be rendered.

u should know how useEffect is working please check examples or read docs. it is very important
https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect